# Why it won't let me install Tomcat from Ansible?

Tags: ssh, permissions, installation, ansible

I'm learning to use Ansible to install Tomcat, I've installed Ansible, created and copies ssh keys, wrote a playbook, but when I tried to run the playbook, it gave me the following error :

```
    <192.168.29.13> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
    <192.168.29.13> REMOTE_MODULE setup
    <192.168.29.13> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/fni/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 192.168.29.13 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436969031.23-114682339176496 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436969031.23-114682339176496'

fatal: [192.168.29.13] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
    while connecting to 192.168.29.13:22
```

I can't understand all of it, but it seems in the last step, it was trying to make a new directory : $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436969031.23-114682339176496

So I checked the permission on the tmp dir, and set it to : rwxrwxrwx

I thought this time it shouldn't have permission problems, so I ran the palybook again, but got a similar error below :

```
    <192.168.29.13> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
    <192.168.29.13> REMOTE_MODULE setup
    <192.168.29.13> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/fni/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 192.168.29.13 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436969284.93-135829741473588 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436969284.93-135829741473588'

fatal: [192.168.29.13] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
    while connecting to 192.168.29.13:22
```

For ssh keys, I've followed the steps in this article, so it shouldn't ask for password anymore : [Why do I still have to enter password after I entered ssh-agent and ssh-add?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415975/why-do-i-still-have-to-enter-password-after-i-entered-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add)

I wonder if anyone else has encountered the same problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: There's no option in the ssh command line to tell it what key it's supposed to use to authenticate. What key should ssh use, and how is it supposed to know which key to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of struggle, I finally found out why, seems my ping requests went through, but playbook commands couldn't, so I did "-vvvv" and compared the results side by side, and found the user Id should have something in front of it : myproject\my_id, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your public key authentication is not working correctly. Check a few things:

1. On the source system from which you run ansible, make sure the private key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) exists and has permissions 400 (r--------)
2. Make sure the public key on the remote system is set up correctly - for the root user in this case, /root/.ssh/authorized_keys should exist and have permissions 600. Also make sure /root/.ssh has permissions 700.
3. Make sure root log in is permitted on the remote system, or (recommended) use another account to log in.

Comment: Thanks. I checked "1" and "2" they are both correct. Only "3" is the problem. There is no /.ssh in root, but the playbook was run as root, so I tried to copy /my_account/.ssh/authorized to /.ssh/authorized and got permission denied.  So then I changed "remote_user: root" in the playbook to "remote_user: my_account", this time it ran as me, which has root access, but still got the same type of error as above. What should I do next ?

Comment: Oh my mistake. Should be 400 but 600 wouldn't cause an error